# Artin's conjecture for $n=2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems

I am interested in the following question:

Is it known that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ for infinitely many primes $p$?

There is some information about Artin's conjecture in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots&oldid=374854868).
I need to know if it is up-to-date and if one can say something about the case $n=2$.

Comment: No. $\!\!\!\!\!$

Comment: @David: there were two questions.
@Kate: Pieter Moree at Bonn will know the most recent advances if there were any.

Comment: 11 years later: still no (to the best of my knowledge).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert, but the content of the article [Artin's primitive root conjecture -a survey -](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412262v1) (modified December 2004) by Pieter Moree suggests the Wikipedia article is reasonably up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

It follows from GRH. Not known on its own.

Comment: yes, the citations to this result are included here: 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots